# How to send a zip to another server

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

I have a form on my website that requires a user to upload a compressed file and fill out information on that file. I send the information to a database and now I need to take that file and move it to my other server to store it in a directory.

I'm currently using cURL to transfer the file over to server 2

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => $file));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://$server/upload.php");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It's not sending the file. What it did send was the temporary path on server 1 which is not what I want. I've never done anything like this before so I am completely lost.

What I need to do is:

1. Send the .zip file over to server 2
2. Unzip the file on server 2 and move the contents to `/home/uploads/`

Both server are linux centos and I'm working on my localhost using Windows.

For testing, in `upload.php` all I did was detect if the request was POST then dump on $_POST to see what data is available and write it to a test text file.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    ob_start();

        var_dump($_POST);

    $data = ob_get_clean();

    $fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);  

} else {

    echo 'You should not be here';

}
```

I can also see a security risk because anybody can upload data to that file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: using FTP is a much better way, see [the php.net ftp manual](http://php.net//manual/en/book.ftp.php)

Comment: I know, however these servers use SSH keys and it will be difficult to do it.

Comment: I don't think PHP needs SSH to use FTP ... aswell, i'm not pro with it so ... but just try, at least you will be fixed :p **PS:** if you use SFTP, then just look at [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-ssh-and-sftp-with-php/)

Comment: `$_FILE` doesn't contain ANY of the actual uploaded data. It just contains data ABOUT the upload. If you want to send the actual file, then you have to do a file upload in curl. oldschoold: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('@file' => $file)` (the `@` is critical), for PHP 5.5+, use [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)

Comment: Using `@file` the dump on `$_POST` returned `array(1) {
  ["@file"]=>
  string(23) "C:\wamp\tmp\phpA173.tmp"
}`

Comment: Once again, my local directory